# Is it possible when using MongoTemplate to dynamically set read preference for a particular query?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

In our application, we manage a number of `MongoTemplate` instances, each representing a client database. For the majority of database operations, we want to use the `secondaryPreferred` read preference in order to leverage our cluster's read replicas and distribute load. However, in at least one case we need to read from the primary to get the most recent data. I don't see any way to override the read preference for this single query. I see [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-902) on the JIRA board, but it's been open for 6 years and associated the StackOverflow link is dead. Assuming that won't be implemented, I'm trying to figure out some alternate solutions. Does this seem like a correct assessment of the possible options?

1. Create two `MongoClient`s with the different read preferences, and use them to create a separate set of `MongoTemplate`s for primary and secondary reads. I'm concerned that this probably creates double the number of connections to the cluster (although perhaps it's not a concern, if the additional connections all go to the secondaries).
2. Use the `MongoTemplate.setReadPreference()` method to temporarily change the read preference before performing the operation, then reset it once finished. It seems like this would be vulnerable to race conditions, however.
3. Sidestep the Spring Data framework and use `executeCommand()` directly, which supports a `readPreference` argument. This means we'd lose all of the benefits and abstraction of Spring Data and have to manipulate the BSON objects directly.
4. The `Query` class has a `slaveOk()` method, but this is the inverse of what I'm looking for and it seems like it's deprecated.

Any further information is appreciated as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround solution we can override the method `prepareCollection(MongoCollection<Document> collection)` in MongoTemplate (refer: [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#prepareCollection-com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection-)) and change the read preference for the needed query alone and let the rest of the cases follow the default read preference

Answer (score -1):

As a side note, seems like `slaveOk()` is doing literally nothing
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/f00991dc293dceee172b1ece6613dde599a0665d/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.java#L3328

```
                        switch (option) {

                        case NO_TIMEOUT:
                            cursorToUse = cursorToUse.noCursorTimeout(true);
                            break;
                        case PARTIAL:
                            cursorToUse = cursorToUse.partial(true);
                            break;
                        case SECONDARY_READS:
                        case SLAVE_OK:
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("%s is no supported flag.", option));
                    }
```